# How can I merge column value in one cell in pandas with respect to another column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, apply

I have one data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'vin':['aaa','aaa','aaa','bbb','ccc','ccc','ddd','eee','eee','fff'],
                    'module':['ABS','ABS','IPMA','BCCM','HPOC','ABS','ABS','HPOC','ABS','ABS']})
```

I want to concatenate all values of column **module** with respect to column **vin**.

Below is my expected output.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'vin':['aaa','aaa','aaa','bbb','ccc','ccc','ddd','eee','eee','fff'],
                    'module':['ABS','ABS','IPMA','BCCM','HPOC','ABS','ABS','HPOC','ABS','ABS'],
                   'New_module':['ABS-ABS-IPMA','ABS-ABS-IPMA','ABS-ABS-IPMA','BCCM','HPOC-ABS','HPOC-ABS','ABS','HPOC-ABS','HPOC-ABS','ABS']})
```

I tried one method, in which I have to duplicate the data frame and apply below code.

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df2, df1.groupby(['vin'])['module'].apply(list), on ='vin', how ='left')
df_merge['module'] = df_merge['module'].astype('str').str.replace("\[|\]|\'| ","")
df_merge
```

Any simple code to get my desired output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `join`:

```
df1['New_module'] = df1.groupby('vin')['module'].transform('-'.join)
```

output:

```
   vin module    New_module
0  aaa    ABS  ABS-ABS-IPMA
1  aaa    ABS  ABS-ABS-IPMA
2  aaa   IPMA  ABS-ABS-IPMA
3  bbb   BCCM          BCCM
4  ccc   HPOC      HPOC-ABS
5  ccc    ABS      HPOC-ABS
6  ddd    ABS           ABS
7  eee   HPOC      HPOC-ABS
8  eee    ABS      HPOC-ABS
9  fff    ABS           ABS
```